# drools working memory backed by cache

Tags: hibernate, drools

Is there a project out there which can use drools working memory using hibernate 2nd level cache ( i.e. if the objects in working memory get too old they get put in a cache )

A second related question is it would be nice if it could be done through hibernate using hibernate 2nd level cache ?